# Rotating a parent rectangle to align child with target

Tags: unity, mathematics, rotation

My beautiful drawings will explain better than many words (or at least I hope):

The structure:

- The black rectangle is a GameObject (my weapon sprite).
- `A` and `B` are also GameObjects (children of black rectangle): `StartShotPoint` and `ShotPoint` used for the direction of my projectile.
- `C` is the first hypothetical target

In this situation my sprite will be rotate of 0 degree.

[image]

In this second image there is the question. I want to find the rotation of my sprite (-10 degree in the example) knowing the `Vector2` destination `D` and of course all the coordinates of the 3 GameObjects.

[image]

The situation is simple as long as the player rotates the weapon, but in this case is the AI (after finding the player at the point `D`) must turn the weapon in the right direction. I know how to find the direction between one point and another, but between two decentralized points and a third one messed up my brain.

I really don't know which "direction" to take.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using [transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)? If it appears to be a valid solution for your context [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/585035/lookat-2d-equivalent-.html) is some further discussion from Unity forums discussing trying to apply it in 2D contexts vs implementing from scratch.

Comment: @disc_code22 Unfortunately I don't think I can use `transform.LookAt` or simply `VectorB - VectorA` to find the direction and then the angle, because the direction must be given by `A` and `B` (go through `A` and `B`) by rotating the rectangle (father of  `A` and `B`). Or at least I can't find the correct way for use `LookAt` in my case (similar in concept, but very different in the specific case).

Comment: Cant you pretty much ignore B, at least when finding the rotation angle? It will always be on the line between A and the target point no? Or how about another conceptual approach: A and B are both offset from the center line of the rectangle by a distance lets call Y. You can call LookAt on the rectangle, but target (Dx, Dy-Y). Thereby you can accommodate for the offset and still take advantage of the LookAt function that already exists. If this sounds like a potential solution I would be happy to expand this comment into a full answer.

Comment: The ideas are interesting! I don't know if I can do tests now because today I'm quite tired (it's a bit late here). But if I will see that the road is right I would be happy to see the complete answer and accept it !! I'll let you know as soon as I did some tests.

Comment: @disc_code22 Mate... is perfect !!! Two lines of code to find the direction! `Vector3 FakeTarget = new Vector3(RealTarget + (ShotPoint - Rectangle.position));` and `direction = FakeTarget - Rectangle.postion`. I don't know how to thank you !!! Indeed, yes I know ... Write the answer and I'll accept it :). Thanks again.

Comment: I think the title of this question could use improvement but I'm struggling to come up with a good title. Maybe "Rotating a parent rectangle to align child with target"? If anyone has other suggestions I would be very open to them. If no more title ideas come in the next couple hours I will go ahead and re-title the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the goal is to be able to rotate a rectangular, which I'll call `sprite`, to line up with an arbitrary point in 2D space, which I'll call `target`.

Rotating `sprite` to line up with `target` can be achieved through the `Transform.LookAt` method provided by Unity, however this alignment will be based upon `sprite`'s center, and we would rather have the target aligned with an arbitrary point within the `sprite`. We'll call this point `firepoint`, as in the case of a gun or cannon sprite, where projectiles need to be fired from a specific point and not just the center of the sprite.

Basically the `Transform.LookAt` nearly gives us the correct rotation, we just need to translate it. Currently it is aligning `sprite` center with `target`, and instead we want `firepoint` aligned with `target`.

To align `firepoint` and `target` we can calculate an `offset target`, that is offset from the `target` position by the same amount that `firepoint` is offset from the `sprite` center. Now, using `offset target` for the `sprite` to `LookAt`, we line up the center point and `offset target`. This ends up aligning `firepoint` and `target` since the difference between both targets and both points is `offset`.

This can be illustrated using the diagrams you provided:

[image: OP Diagram 1]

Looking at the diagram above, imagine that we have been given our `target` as point C. To align `firepoint` and C, we need the `sprite` to `LookAt` D, the point that exactly `offset` away from `C`.

[image: Annotated OP Diagram 2]

Looking at the above diagram, which I have shoddily modified, we have a `target` D, also I have added an `offset target` E below point D by amount `offset`. By `LookAt`'ing the rect towards `offset target` E we will end up lining up `firepoint` with the `target`.

Further information can be found [in the Unity Docs on LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html), as well as in [this Unity forum thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/585035/lookat-2d-equivalent-.html) where users discussed how to recreate or use the `LookAt` function effectively in a 2D context.